Terraform to link Fabric capacity with a workspace
I'm trying to create a terraform that assigns a Fabric Capacity to a fabric workspace (Power BI.com)
I have managed to create the capacity and the workspaces from terraform but for some reason I keep getting an error on the providers when trying to link the capacity to the workspace.
I'm logging in with Az login and authenticating with an account that has access to both the capacity and workspaces.
main.tf
# Assign workspace to capacity
resource "microsoftfabric_workspace_capacity_assignment" "workspace_assignment" {
  workspace_id = var.workspace_id
  capacity_id  = var.capacity_id
}

variables.tf
variable "workspace_id" {
  description = "The ID of the Fabric workspace"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

variable "capacity_id" {
  description = "The ID of the Fabric capacity"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

providers.tf
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>3.0"
    }
    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = "~>3.0"
    }
    azapi = {
      source  = "Azure/azapi"
      version = "1.15.0"
    }
    fabric = {
      source  = "microsoft/fabric"
      version = "0.1.0-beta.4"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "azapi" {
  # Configuration options

  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
}

provider "fabric" {}

outputs.tf
output "workspace_capacity_assignment_id" {
  value = microsoftfabric_workspace_capacity_assignment.workspace_assignment.id
}

The error I keep getting is
Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/microsoftfabric: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named
│ registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/microsoftfabric
│
│ All modules should specify their required_providers so that external consumers will get the correct providers when using a module. To see which modules are currently depending on
│ hashicorp/microsoftfabric, run the following command:
│     terraform providers


I am able to reproduce your issue.
Running terraform providers command as mentioned in the error message, we can see there are 2 providers related to Microsoft Fabric:
Providers required by configuration:
.
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm] ~> 3.0
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/microsoftfabric]
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random] ~> 3.0
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/azure/azapi] 1.15.0
└── provider[registry.terraform.io/microsoft/fabric] 0.1.0-beta.4

So it seems you're using the wrong provider for the microsoftfabric_workspace_capacity_assignment resource.
Instead of using Microsoft Fabric Provider:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    # other providers here 

    fabric = {
      source  = "microsoft/fabric"
      version = "0.1.0-beta.4"
    }
  }
}

# other providers here

provider "fabric" {}

Try using microsoftfabric Provider provider (managed by Christopher Nagl):
terraform {
  required_providers {
    # other providers here 

    microsoftfabric = {
      source = "ChristopherNagl/microsoftfabric"
      version = "0.5.1"
    }
  }
}

# other providers here

provider "microsoftfabric" {}

Note:

Change fabric to microsoftfabric in providers.tf otherwise the same error will occur.


Thank you, I believe this will resolve my issue. Just need to get an app registry created and a service account to use for the connections strings. Do you know why both are required? I.e.
provider "microsoftfabric" {
client_id     = "xxx"
client_secret = "Txxx"
tenant_id     = "9xxx"
username      = "xx"
password      = "xx"
}
Assume Client ID and Secret is for an app registry, but why do you also need a username and password? Do some of the different scripts require an actual account rather then a app registry to do the install?

@JoelG to be honest I don't know the answer to your question. Maybe you don't need both. Check the provider's documentation.

@JoelG try excluding username and password and see what happens.

Ok thanks again for your help. I'll try just using the client id and secret and see how I get on.
